# plt.hist - weight factor of counts by factor 0.0667

Tags: python

I have successfully created a histogram from a `list x`.

the counts of the hist should be multiplied by the factor 0.0667.
if I use the weight function of `plt.hist` I get an error.

this is what I already tried!

```
counts= plt.hist(x,bins=[0,0.01,0.02], weights=(x*0.06666), facecolor='grey')
```

I guess its a quite simple question but I am new to python!

Answer (score 1):

In Python you cannot multiply a list with a factor (unless you work with `numpy` arrays, which maybe is the best idea in this case anyway).

Try

```
x_weights = [i*0.06666 for i in x]
counts = plt.hist(x,bins=[0,0.01,0.02], weights=x_weights, facecolor='grey')
```

or

```
import numpy as np
counts= plt.hist(x,bins=[0,0.01,0.02], weights=np.asarray(x)*0.06666, facecolor='grey')
```

Also, your weights looks like it has been rounded. You should consider saving the weighting factor to a local variable and then use it when plotting the histograms

Edit: Now that I am (hopefully) aware of the true problem, here is how you can work with your data:

Numpy arrays can and should be multi-dimensional. If you have 15 simulations of 332 outputs, that should naturally result in a 2D-array of shape (15L, 332L) meaning that you get a matrix with 15 rows and 332 columns.

### Step 1:

Prepare your numpy array:

```
x = np.zeros(shape=(15,332)) # this creates a 2D-matrix full of "0"
```

### Step 2:

Write the output of each simulation into the respective row:

```
for i_run in range(15):
    x[i_run,:] =  # result of the simulation # i_run
```

### Step 3:

Calculate the average of your 332 values for the 15 simulation runs:

```
x_mean = np.mean(x, axis=0)
```

`axis=0` tells python to calculate the mean of your columns. `axis=1` would return the mean of your rows.

### Step 4:

Now you can simply plot the histogram of these mean values:

```
counts = plt.hist(x_mean,bins=[0,0.01,0.02], facecolor='grey')
```

What still confuses me is that you speak of "counts". A "count" to me is an integer. I can only count "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..." not "0, 0, 0, 0.11, 0.11, 0.15, ..."

Comment: i understand what you are doing! option 2 seems to be the answer for me because i am not allowed to change the data from the list, sadly i get an error if i try it! ValueError: weights should have the same shape as x

Comment: Your error is puzzling me. You take `x` as it is and multiply it with a factor. How should that change the shape of the array? Is it possible that you provide `x` or at least tell us what `x.shape` returns?

Comment: i have a list x with 5000 float numbers from 15 different simulations like [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0011, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0018, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0027, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001]. now i need the average amount of counts from the 15 simulations, so i just want to divide my counts by 15! i thought if i weight each count by the factor 1/15 this will do the job! are there other possibilities?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. `x` is a list of len(5000), containing floating point values. What do you mean by "average counts"? And how did the 15 simulations contribute to `x`? Do you have 15 lists of len(5000)?

Comment: Each Simulation creates a list of 332 numbers. i created a an array x which combines the 15*332 numbers = 4980 numbers in one array. if i use plt.hist(x, bins=[0,0.01,0.02]) i get a histogram which counts the numbers of the array x(all simulations). actually i need the average amount of counts so i need something like plt.hist([x / 15]). I need to divide the bin_height of my plt.hist(x) by 15. is there a way to do this?

Comment: thanks for your help! i was able to solve the problem by myselfl, i attached the code as answer :)

Comment: That's good news! Please consider using 2D-matrices anyway. It's a very basic principle you should know how to implement!

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [liste_FED_all]
zz = [0.066666667]*4980
counts= plt.hist(x, bins=[0,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.2,0.3,1], weights= zz, facecolor='grey',edgecolor='black')
```

the weight function was just right, i had to set a weight for every single number of the array x. therefore i created the array zz which provides 4980 times my factor for each number of the array x! was quite simple took me 10 hours! i still have a lot to learn! :)

Comment: Still a bit confused about what's the sense of giving the same weight to each data point. Maybe the code does what you want, but it's really not the best result you can come up with.